# Doctor who's Listen timeline vs Utopia

Tags: doctor-who

David Tennant told that Tardis never, and never could've travel that much in time. It's in the end of the universe. It's impossible. (3x11)

Peter Capaldi told in Listen that Tardis shouldn't have came that far but some fool close off the shields.  (8x4)

My question is, which is older in datetime? If both doctors told that it's the end of the universe, which one of the episodes is older in time?  Utopia or Listen?

If Listen is more timedate older, how did the Doctor came so easy there if David Tennant told that it's impossible to travel that much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Utopia*'s End of the Universe would be older

in *Listen* we see where Orson's ship is

[image: Orson's Ship at the End of the Universe]

however in *Utopia* we see what Earth is like

[image: Martha and Jack at the End of the Universe]

the difference is indicated by The Doctor in *Utopia*

> **MARTHA:** Is that a city? 
>   **DOCTOR:** A city or a hive, or a nest, or a conglomeration. Like it was grown. But look, there. That's like pathways, roads? Must have been some sort of life, long ago. 
>   **MARTHA:** What killed it? 
>   **DOCTOR:** Time. Just time. Everything's dying now. All the great civilizations have gone. This isn't just night. **All the stars have burned up and faded away into nothing.**

Source: [chakoteya > Utopia](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/29-11.htm)

in *Utopia* time has proceeded so far ahead that all the stars have burned out leaving nothing but darkness while in *Listen* we see in the background that there is a star

Comment: That scene in Utopia is clearly lit. It's not from the TARDIS and not from any civilisation, so there must also be a nearby star.